# JS Browser with pause function, help please

Tags: javascript, function, browser

I wrote this program in js that goes through a list of URLs, where it stays on each page for a few seconds, closes the current window, and open the next in line. Everything works perfect, now I need it to stop/pause every 5 links. The second part of this project would be to create my own browser that open up like a program and there would be three buttons (start, continue, stop, maybe pause as well). I'd like start button to obviously start the function which goes through the pages, continue would be when it pauses on the fifth link I'd like a pop up message to say "wake up" and have the option to click "ok" only. Then you would have to click on continue in order for the function to continue. Stop would stop the function no matter where it has reached in the list. I'd like the links to show up in my browser not in Google Chrome or any other. What program should I use to design the browser? Here is the code of the current program:

```
var urlList = ['www.youtube.com',
            'www.google.com', 
            'www.bing.com',
            'www.yahoo.com', 
            'www.facebook,com',
            'www.windows.com', 
            'www.opera.com',];
var wnd;
var curIndex = 0; // a var to hold the current index of the current url

function openWindow(){
    wnd = window.open(urlList[curIndex], '', '');
    if (curIndex % 5 == 0) {
                           }
    setTimeout(function () {
         wnd.close(); //close current window
         curIndex++; //increment the index
         if(curIndex < urlList.length) openWindow(); //open the next window if the array isn't at the end
}, 4000);
}
openWindow();
```

Help me finish the if statement...

Comment: So... you want to actually write a browser *in* JavaScript, *not* within another browser?

Comment: I want a browser, not sure in what language, the program I wrote is in JavaScript, but you have the idea. I don't want to use Chrome or Mozilla, I want a program that displays the links from the array within the program. if that makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable for your timeout period, instead of using the value 4000. Note that it must have global scope. I've added a variable called`delay` here:

```
var wnd;
var curIndex = 0; // a var to hold the current index of the current url
var delay;
```

Then, use the new variable in your `openWindow()` function, setting its value to a longer period in your `if` statement when you want the pauses to happen.

I've used a ternary operator here for instead of an `if` statement, but you could use an `if` statement just as well:

```
function openWindow(){
    wnd = window.open('http://' + urlList[curIndex], '', '');

    // pause for 30 seconds instead of 4 if the condition is met
    delay = (curIndex > 0 && curIndex % 3 == 0 ? 30000 : 4000)

    setTimeout(function () {
         wnd.close(); //close current window
         curIndex++; //increment the index
         if(curIndex < urlList.length) openWindow(); //open the next window if the array isn't at the end
}, delay);
}
```

Comment: this would pause every 3 links?